# Jquery Ajax Call works only one time until i restart the application

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My ajax call works only the first time. After that I get an Method not allowed exception.
Here is my java script code:

```
 $('.AppFormFormNewOT').submit(function () {

    var formID = $(this).attr('id');

    var appDate = $('#' + formID + ' .dateHiddenInput').val();
    var appMit = $('#' + formID + ' .mitHiddenInput').val();
    var am = $('#' + formID + ' .amCheckBox').attr('checked');
    var pm = $('#' + formID + ' .pmCheckBox').attr('checked');

    if (!am && !pm) {
        alert("Bitte geben Sie einen Halbtag an");
        return false;
    }
    var vorOrNach;
    if (am == 'true,false') {
        vorOrNach = 'FirstHalfDayHasAppointment';
    } else {
        vorOrNach = 'SecondHalfDayHasAppointment'
    }

    var url = 'Plan/' + vorOrNach + "/";
    var occupied = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        datatype: 'text',
        async: false,
        data: {
            date: appDate,
            id_person: appMit
        },
        success: function (data) {
            occupied = data;
            if (occupied == "True") {
                alert("Hier ist bereits ein Termin");
                return false;
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Ajax error');
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);
            return false;
        }


    });
    if (occupied == "True" || occupied == true) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }


});
```

The method it calls are simple:

```
[ScriptMethod][HttpPost]
    public string FirstHalfDayHasAppointment(DateTime date, int id_person)
    {
          bool hasApp = repo.dateWithPersonAlreadyHasApp(date, id_person, HalfDay.AM);
          return hasApp.ToString();


    }

    [ScriptMethod][HttpPost]
    public string SecondHalfDayHasAppointment(DateTime date, int id_person)
    {
        bool hasApp = repo.dateWithPersonAlreadyHasApp(date, id_person, HalfDay.PM);
        return hasApp.ToString();
    }
```

When I restart the application (not just reloading the page), again the first call works and any following calls fail again.

edit: When i just return true in the functions the ajax calls always succeed:

```
  [ScriptMethod][HttpPost]
    public string FirstHalfDayHasAppointment(DateTime appDate, int id_person)
    {
        return "True";



    }

    [ScriptMethod][HttpPost]
    public string SecondHalfDayHasAppointment(DateTime appDate, int id_person)
    {
        return "True";

    }
```

So the problem seems to be on the server side. But I don't know what this has to do with ajax and why ajax returns a method not allowed exception. Hope this information is useful. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any reason for setting `async: false`? That's killing the whole purpose of AJAX. In fact that's not AJAX. It's SJAX. Also `[ScriptMethod]`? In ASP.NET MVC? Why? There are controller actions that should be used in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: As far as I know if I don't set it to false, the form will be submited immediately.

Comment: no, it will not be submitted immediately if you return false from the submit handler.

Comment: add e.preventDefault(); on the line before the "var formID etc..." instead of all the return false or true. then remove async:false

Comment: Are you seeing any error when you submit the request the 2nd time?  If so, what error are you seeing?

Comment: the first message i get is 'error' the second 'method not allowed'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the name of the variable 'url' to another name, for example 'myurl' and I worked. It seems the variable 'url' has some predefined value.